# Spree Dropdown boxes for variant option values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree, form-for

I'm learning Spree 3.0 and I have a setup a test shop that sells shorts.

Shorts has multiple option types: Size, Color, Length

I wanted to change the way it displays the variant options on the frontend from a radio checkbox to a drop down box.

Currently, Spree displays the option types as radio buttons:

[image: Current Spree setup]

I want to change this to use drop down menus for each option type, like this:

[image: What I want Spree to do]

I've tried the following:

```
<%= select_tag "variant_id", options_for_select(@product.variants_and_option_values(current_currency).collect{ |v| ["#{variant_options(v)}  #{variant_price(v)}", v.id] })%>
```

But it simply displays the values of all option types in each tag:

[image: Dropdown with all the option types 1]

[image: Dropdown with all the option types 2]

I wanted to know the best way to split the option values into individual dropdown menus?

Any assistance is my much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This is not as easy as it looks since you will be using `Spree::OptionValue` records instead of variants and at some point you will want to convert back to variants in order to add it to your cart. Combinations might not be possible and/or out of stock so it is highly unpractical to work with option_values.

But nonetheless, you wanted to know how so i set up the following:

```
@options = Spree::OptionValue.joins(:option_value_variants).where(spree_option_value_variants: { variant_id: @product.variant_ids }).group_by(&:option_type)
```

This will give you a hash with the keys of the hash being option_types (Size, Color, Length in your case) and the values being arrays of option_values.

You can easily form this into radios like this:

```
<% @options.each do |option_type, option_values| %>
  <%= content_tag :h2, option_type.presentation %>
  <% option_values.each do |option_value| %>
    <%= radio_button_tag option_type.name, option_value.id %>
    <%= label_tag option_value.presentation %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Or for dropdowns:

```
<% @options.each do |option_type, option_values| %>
  <%= content_tag :h2, option_type.presentation %>
  <%= collection_select :variants, option_type.name, option_values, :id, :presentation %>
<% end %>
```

And in your controller you would want to find a variant matching those 3 criteria, check if it is `in_stock`, `backorderable` or `track_inventory?` is `false` and respond with errors or an updated cart :)

I hope this helped

Comment: Thanks for the response Fabian. It looks difficult. I was looking at dropdown boxes specifically. Maybe, a Javascript solution might be the answer, hiding the radios.

Comment: Radio's can be converted to a select easily. its the same kind of thing, pick one option from an array of options within a context. I have implemented this before in a SPA and i used the api to get all the variants from a product, then for the variants which where `in_stock: true` i collected the option values and displayed only those option_values to the user. Or maybe gray out the options for out of stock variants

Comment: Thanks again @Fabian de Pabian, I'll need to digest this and figure out how to implement it. I can simply convert radio to dropdown but it has options types per product on a single dropdown, instead of seperate dropdown for color; size; etc..

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to solve this problem. It basically takes the `variant_id` parameter that was controlled by the radio buttons and turns it into a hidden field controlled by jQuery and AJAX with additional notifications.

I hope this helps someone.

*config/routes.rb*

```
# Mount the core routes
Rails.application.routes.draw do 
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, at: '/'
end

# Create new routes
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.draw do 
  post "products/:product_id/get_variant",
       to: "products#toggle_like",
       as: "get_variant",
       constraints: { :format => /(js)/ }
end
```

*app/models/spree/product_decorator.rb*

```rb
Spree::Product.class_eval do

  # Find the Product's Variant from an array of OptionValue ids
  def find_variant_by_options(array)
    option_values = Spree::OptionValue.where(id: array)
    variants = []
    option_values.each do |option_value|
      variants.push(option_value.variants.ids)
    end
    self.variants.find_by(:id => variants.inject(:&).first)
  end
end
```

*app/controllers/spree/products_controller_decorator.rb*

```rb
Spree::ProductsController.class_eval do

  # Get the Variant from params[:ids], respond with JavaScript
  def get_variant
    @product = Spree::Product.find_by :slug => params[:product_id]
    @variant = @product.find_variant_by_options(params[:ids].split(','))

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

*app/views/spree/products/get_variant.js.erb*

```javascript
// Update hidden field #varient_id's value. 
$("#variant_id").val("<%= @variant.id %>") 
// Update price
$(".price.selling").html("<%= number_to_currency @variant.price %>");
<% if @variant.in_stock? && @variant.available? %> 
// If in stock and available
  $("#add-to-cart-button").prop("disabled", false); // Enable button
  $(".out-of-stock").hide(); // Hide 'out of stock' message
<% else %> 
// Otherwise
  $("#add-to-cart-button").prop("disabled", true); // Disable button
  $(".out-of-stock").show(); // Show 'out of stock' message
<% end %>
```

*app/views/spree/products/_cart_form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for order, url: populates_orders_path do |f| %>
  ...
  <% if @product.variants_and_option_values(current_currency).any? %>
    <div id="product_variants" class="col-md-6">
      <h3 class="product-section-title"><%= Spree.t(:variants) %></h3>
      <% @product.option_types.each do |option_type| %>
        <%= f.label "option_type_#{option_type.id}", option_type.name %>
        <br>
        <%= f.select "option_type_value_#{option_type.id}",
                     option_type.option_values.all.collect { |v| [ v.name, v.id ] },
                     { include_blank: true },
                     { class: "form-control" } %>
        <br>
      <% end %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag "variant_id", value: "0" %>
      ...
     </div>
  <% else %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "variant_id", @product.master.id %>
  <% end %>
  ...
    <span class="price selling" 
          itemprop="price" 
          content="<%= @product.price_in(current_currency).amount.to_d %>">
      <%= display_price(@product) %>
    </span>
  ...
    <%= button_tag class: "btn btn-success",
                      id: "add-to-cart-button",
                disabled: @product.variants.any?,
                    type: :submit do %>
      <%= Spree.t(:add_to_cart) %>
    <% end %>
  ...
  <span class="out-of-stock" style="display: none;">
    <%= Spree.(:out_of_stock) %>
  </span>
<% end %>

<script>
  // Call AJAX if all options are selected, otherwise clean up.
  $("#product-variants select").change(function(){
    var option_value_ids = [];
    $("#product-variants select").each(function(){
      option_value_ids.push($(this).val());
    });
    if(option_value_ids.indexOf("") == -1){
      $.ajax({
        url: "<%= get_variant_path(@product) %>?ids=" + option_value_ids.join(','),
        method: "post"
      });
    }else{
      $("#variant_id").val("0");
      $("#add-to-cart-button").prop("disabled", true);
      $(".out-of-stock").hide();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: That's awesome! Some corrections through: in routes `products#get_variant` instead of `products#toggle_like`. Also for some reason the `find_variant_by_options` method was not working for me, so I made a full query, which looks like this: `@variant = Spree::Variant.joins(:option_value_variants).where(
      spree_option_value_variants: {option_value_id: params[:ids].split(',')},
      product: @product).first`. Haven't fully tested it though.